# Read schema.org JSON in React

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, gatsby

I have a React Gatsby app with Axios to read and render schema.org JobPosting JSON feed and display it in a page at runtime.

I'm able to load the JSON but I'm having trouble traversing it (if that's the right term).

The JSON looks like this..

```
[
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "JobPosting",
    "datePosted": "2019-10-24T08:56:35+00:00",
    "description": "description here",
    "hiringOrganization": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "Evooq",
      "department": { "@type": "Organization", "name": "Technology" },
      "logo": "https://hire.withgoogle.com/public_frame/jobs/evooqch/logo/P_AAAAABlAAAVKRjuodf8v8_.png"
    },
    "identifier": {
      "@type": "PropertyValue",
      "name": "Evooq",
      "value": "P_AAAAABlAAAVA0RlA-fYhv0"
    },
    "jobLocation": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "Lausanne",
        "addressRegion": "VD",
        "addressCountry": "CH"
      }
    },
    "title": "Front-End Software Engineer",
    "url": "https://hire.withgoogle.com/public/jobs/evooqch/view/P_AAAAABlAAAVA0RlA-fYhv0",
    "employmentType": "Full time"
  },
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "JobPosting",
    "datePosted": "2019-10-24T08:56:35+00:00",
    "description": "description here",
    "hiringOrganization": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "Evooq",
      "department": { "@type": "Organization", "name": "Technology" },
      "logo": "https://hire.withgoogle.com/public_frame/jobs/evooqch/logo/P_AAAAABlAAAVKRjuodf8v8_.png"
    },
    "identifier": {
      "@type": "PropertyValue",
      "name": "Evooq",
      "value": "P_AAAAABlAAAVA0RlA-fYhv0"
    },
    "jobLocation": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "Lausanne",
        "addressRegion": "VD",
        "addressCountry": "CH"
      }
    },
    "title": "Front-End Software Engineer",
    "url": "https://hire.withgoogle.com/public/jobs/evooqch/view/P_AAAAABlAAAVA0RlA-fYhv0",
    "employmentType": "Full time"
  }
]
```

After loading it, I save it in a state variable

```
  state = {
    JobData: [],
  }
```

In the Axios fetch function I update the state, it only works if I JSON stringitfy

```
this.setState({ JobData: JSON.stringify(res.data) })
```

All the JSON data displays with

```
<p> {this.state.JobData} </p>
```

but I want to loop through the children and pull out the titles etc, something like

```
            <ul>
              {this.state.JobData.map(node => (
                <li key={node.datePosted}>
                  <a href={node.url} target="_blank">
                    {node.title}
                  </a>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
```

The above doesn't work, I get TypeError: this.state.JobData.map is not a function

Comment: A minor improvement, I suggest using the index provided by map as the key, the datePosted might not be as unique depending on how it is handled by the server. `map((node, index) =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `JSON.stringify` you should use `JSON.parse` (*if the response isn't a json already. i.e. has header `application/json`*)

`JSON.stringify` takes a JSON object and converts it to a string.

`JSON.parse` takes a string, and tries to convert it into a JSON object.

In your case you have a JSON string, and you want to convert it into a JSON object, using the `parse` method.

---

*Below is just general knowledge that you might not need or might not be applicable in your case.*

If your JSON string isn't standard JSON (unquoted keys for example), you could use a tool like [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) to parse your string instead of the native JavaScript JSON API.

Comment: With JSON.parse I'm not getting the error when using map, but the JobData state is now empty

Comment: Try breaking out the `res.data` parsing to a variable and console.log it before you set it to state and make sure it logs a valid value in the console

Comment: console.log(res.data) logs the object but console.log(JSON.parse(res.data)) is empty

Comment: Could you please paste the string returned by `res.data` into codepen or a similar place and give me a link to debug it?

Comment: Wait, if `console.log(res.data)` is logging the object, not the string version of it, then you don't need to do anything.
This could be the case if the response has a header `application/json` then the payload/data would be automatically parsed as a JSON object.

Comment: will this do, its the JSON feed and is the same as what is being returned by res.data - https://hire.withgoogle.com/v2/api/t/evooqch/public/jobs

Comment: without parse or stringify I get this error - ×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {@context, @type, datePosted, description, hiringOrganization, identifier, jobLocation, title, url, employmentType}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: The API link you sent definitely returns a JSON if you inspect the request in the network tab of the dev tools https://imgur.com/a/rsZ7IKq

Comment: The error you get is for using `<p> {this.state.JobData} </p>`. This error happens when you try to use an object in the render template directly. It should work fine with your object.map and only using the json to extract its data to be used with valid template elements like you do with <a>.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202460/discussion-between-jakekempo-and-abido).